# What is the value of $\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{1}}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is this known? Can we at least relate it to $\aleph_{2}$?

Comment: It is $2^{\aleph_1}$: $2^{\aleph_1}≤\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{1}}≤(2^{\aleph_1})^{\aleph_{1}}=2^{\aleph_1\times\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}$, and assuming AC we have $2^{\aleph_1}>\aleph_1$ so $2^{\aleph_1}≥\aleph_2$, without AC we can't say anything apart from $2^{\aleph_1}\not<\aleph_2$

Comment: $\aleph_1^{\aleph_1} \ge 2^{\aleph_1} \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ and the standard axioms of set theory are not enough to determine whether $2^{\aleph_0} >\aleph_2$ or${}=\aleph_2$ or${}<\aleph_2. \qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments already said:

$$2^{\aleph_1} \le \aleph_1^{\aleph_1} \le (2^{\aleph_1})^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_1}$$ so it equals $2^{\aleph_1} = |\mathscr{P}(\aleph_1)|$.

It's $\ge \aleph_2$, of course, but can be equal to it in some models of ZFC and strictly larger (say $\aleph_{100}$) in others. It's independent of ZFC (like CH is).